# Сложение результатов из текстового файла с помощью php

Tags: php, веб-программирование, текст

Здравствуйте, есть текстовый файл с текстом и цифрами.
Задача: считать текст, сложить цифры и сохранить в другом файле.
Например, в файле написано:
ИванИвановичИвановДегтяревМеряев111100111

Нужно, чтобы php файл посчитал все единицы, и записал значения в новый текстовый файл в виде:

Иван Иванович Иванов, Дегтярев, Меряев, 7

Comment: Строки в файле всегда в формате:
`ФИОФФцифры`
или возможны варианты?

Comment: у Вас исходная строка `ИванИвановичИвановДегтяревМеряев` не ровняется полученной `Иван Иванович Иванов, Дегтярев, Меряев,`
уточните вопрос на наличие форматирования и словаря слов или же регулярного выражения  по которому выдергиваются слова

Comment: Извиняюсь, что сразу не задал формат, моя ошибка. Должно быть ФИОФФФцифры.

Comment: Почему не равняется? Равняется, но с пробелами и запятыми, да. Если это не возможно, то это другой вопрос.

Comment: " уточните вопрос на наличие форматирования и словаря слов или же регулярного выражения по которому выдергиваются слова", Нет. к сожалению, ни форматирования, ни выражения по которому выдергиваются слова. Есть только ограниченный список трех фамилий, которые идут после фио, если надо - могу предоставить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('file.txt'); //берем данные из файла

preg_match_all("/[А-Я][а-я]+/", $file, $names); //парсим ФиоФФФ
preg_match_all("/\d{1}/", $file, $numbers); //парсим цифры

$sum = 0;

//перебираем массив с цифрами
foreach($numbers[0] as $num) {
    $sum = $sum + $num; //складываем
}

//собираем данные
$data = $names[0][0].' '.$names[0][1].' '.$names[0][2].', '.$names[0][3].', '.$names[0][4].', '.$names[0][5].', '.$sum;

//записываем в новый файл
file_put_contents('new_file.txt', $data);
```

Comment: В файле написано "ИванИвановичИвановДегтяревСпиридоновБогачева11111110111" , в новый файл записывается только ", , , , 10 "

Comment: Версия php какая? На 5.6, у меня, все нормально работает.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1577ae088cf94b973bf34a6327da3fabfa814a76